# Proxies from a file with Requests

Tags: python, proxy

How do I use proxies from a text file with requests? 
The proxies in the file are in the format: ip:port
So I can't really build a dict like {'scheme' : 'scheme://ip:port'}

And I need to access two different sites with the same proxy and then switch the proxy. One of the site uses HTTP and the other uses HTTPS.

I tried doing this for the HTTP request:

```
response = c.get(url, proxies = {'http': 'http://'+p})
```

And this for the HTTPS request:

```
response = c.get(url, proxies = {'https': 'https://'+p})
```

But the first one doesn't work and throws me an error.

Any workarounds for this?

Comment: *“So I can't really build a dict”* – Why not? Just parse the file and build a dictionary. *“But the first one doesn't work and throws me an error”* – What is the full error, what exactly are you doing, what is the value of `p`, etc. You need to provide more information than that if you want us to help you.

Comment: The page doesn't load. I mean I check for a particular cookie and it is assigned to NoneType.

Comment: It *throws me an error* . What exactly is the error?

Answer (score 1):

My assumption is that it fails due to an untrusted SSL certificate.

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:503: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

To solve this, read the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830901/python-requests-throwing-ssl-errors/30831120#30831120)

However, if you get any similar message to this

> Connection to server refused.

It can be caused by many reasons, such as firewall blocking the port or proxy is configured badly. Anyway, to see if that is a bug in your program, try to use the proxy (SSL) in your browser and surf the internet.

**Regarding your second question**, that shouldn't be a problem.
For instance, the file `proxies.txt` has the following data:

```
172.17.0.3:443
172.17.0.23:9443
172.17.0.34:80
```

Then, you can infer the scheme according to the port number. It is very common that ports that end with `443` are `HTTPS`.

```
with open('proxies.txt', 'r') as data
    lines = data.readlines()

proxies = {'http': [], 'https': []}
for line in lines:
    ip_port = line.split(':')
    ip, port = (ip_port[0], ip_port[1]) if len(ip_port) > 1 else (ip_port[0], 80)
    scheme = 'http'
    if port.endswith('443'):
        scheme = 'https'
    proxies[scheme].append(join([scheme, '://', ip, ':', port]))
```

Comment: The page doesn't load. I mean I check for a particular cookie and it is assigned to NoneType.

Comment: what do you mean the `cookie` is assigned to `None`? You don't get any error message? What is the response's `status_code` and `headers`, or anything that gives more information about the problem.

Comment: I get a connection refused error.