# Python requests throwing SSL errors

Tags: python, macos, ssl, python-requests

This is a followup to [SSLError using requests for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419381/sslerror-using-requests-for-python):

I have just installed `requests` on a Mac OSX 10.8.5.  My first attempt at doing `requests.get` failed on missing certificate:

`SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`

- The thread above says to look for `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/re‌​quests/cacert.pem` but actually I don't even have a `.../site-packages/requests` directory.  It's not clear to me if this should have been added by the installation (I used `pip`)
- Further threads and the `requests` docs say to install `certifi`, so I did.  But now I get a different error:

  ```
  python -c 'import requests; requests.get("https://api.github.com/events")'    /usr/lib/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
    InsecurePlatformWarning
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
    File "/usr/lib/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 431, in send
      raise SSLError(e, request=request)
  requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm
  ```

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question ? You need to specify with clarity a question that you would like the community help you with.

Comment: This kind of error is common with older OpenSSL versions and  certificates signed with SHA-256. Which version of OpenSSL you are using (`openssl version`)?

Comment: `OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013`

Answer (score 9):

Notice that you're using `HTTPS`. As mentioned in the [Requests manual](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)

> To check a host’s SSL certificate, you can use the verify argument [...] By default, verify is set to True

Here are few ways to fix that:

### Update OpenSSL (probably will solve your problem)

Taken from [here](https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/old_openssl_sha256.html):

> If you encounter one of the following errors:
>
> ```
> error:0D0890A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_verify:unknown message digest algorithm
> error:0D0C50A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:unknown message digest algorithm
> The software you are using might be compiled with a version too old of OpenSSL that does not take certificates signed with sha256WithRSAEncryption into account.
> ```
>
> It requires at least OpenSSL 0.9.8o for a total management of SHA256. OpenSSl 0.9.7m only assures a partial management, for server
>   mode only.

#### Check your `openssl` version by

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1k-fips 8 Jan 2015
```

If you have a smaller version than `OpenSSL0.9.8o`, you have to update its version (OS X):

```
brew update
brew install openssl
brew link --force openssl
```

If that doesn't work, try this way:

```
brew uninstall openssl
rm -rf /usr/local/openssl
brew install openssl
```

- there's an issue with `openssl` installed before `OS X 10.10.3` and reinstalling it fixes it
- these command lines will uninstall `openssl`, remove its folder from your hard-disk and install it again (the updated version)

#### Install `certifi`

Taken from [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ca-certificates)

> By default Requests bundles a set of root CAs that it trusts, sourced
>   from the Mozilla trust store. However, these are only updated once for
>   each Requests version. This means that if you pin a Requests version
>   your certificates can become extremely out of date.
>
> From Requests version 2.4.0 onwards, Requests will attempt to use
>   certificates from certifi if it is present on the system. This allows
>   for users to update their trusted certificates without having to
>   change the code that runs on their system.
>
> For the sake of security we recommend upgrading certifi frequently!

In other word, try to install `certifi`, if you have `Request 2.4.0` or newer:

```
pip install certifi
```

Hopefully, this will fix the problem.

#### Use different version of OpenSSL and Requests

Looking into it using Google, I have found that there is a problem with OpenSSL in Python 2:

- https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/465#issuecomment-76520363
- https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/38226
- https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1484

However, I am using `Python 2.7.6`, `Requests 2.2.1` and `OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014` and everything runs correctly.

### Pass the certificate

In other cases, you may need to tell `requests.get` the path to the certificate file, if the host's certificate was signed by you.

```
requests.get("https://api.github.com/events", verify=True, cert=['/path/to/my/ca.crt'])
```

### Set the verify argument to False (NOT RECOMMENDED!)

In case you want to avoid the certificate verification, you have to pass `verify=False` to the `request.get` method.

```
python -c 'import requests; requests.get("https://api.github.com/events", verify=False)'
```

or from `script.py` file:

```
import requests
res = requests.get("https://api.github.com/events", verify=False)
print res
```

terminal:

```
$ python script.py
<Response [200]>
```

***Important***:  Very bad idea; You can be [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacked, which is a critical security vulnerability.

Comment: Please never suggest to disable certificate validation without describing the negative effects (man-in-the-middle attack) and that it should only be used for testing or if security is otherwise not relevant.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich but that's what I did. I didn't mention MITMA but I did say "*trust* the host". Isn't that good enough?

Comment: That's not the question of trusting the host. TLS does not say anything about how trusted the host is, only if the certificate matches the hostname and was issued by a trusted CA. You might not trust `attacker.example.com` but the certificate might still be fine. The problem with disabling validation is that you don't know if you talk to the host at all.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, can you review my updated post, please? 10x.

Comment: Yes I was using https -- that's the example in the requests doc.

Comment: @GideonAv, that's great. Then, I am guessing the problem is that you have an old version of `openssl`. did you read my post and update it?

Comment: See above: version appears to be up to date:  `OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013`

Comment: @GideonAv, read https://github.com/docker/docker-py/issues/465#issuecomment-76520363, https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/38226 and https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1484. It seems Requests 2.5.x has problems with different versions of OpenSSL. But I am running Requests 2.2.1 and OpenSSL 1.0.1k and it works fine... so try to use these versions and let me know.

Comment: @GideonAv, hey! I was wondering if my answer helped you resolve the problem. Notice, I have updated it more than once, since the last time. Please, let me know.

Comment: I gave up, because it looks like keeping OpenSSL up-to-date is too much of a hassle.  

But thanks for the suggestions of course.

Comment: @GideonAv sorry for bothering you but as i suggested in my answer, you can use a newer version of Requests (2.4.0+) and install certifi too. this will take the updating OpenSSL out of the equation. Did you try it?

Comment: @bshuster13 as far as I can tell this is the newest version -- I used 'pip install' on June 14 and checked again with --upgrade today.

I just noticed this: 
`/usr/lib/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.`

Comment: So, now you don't get any certification error, right? To fix this insecure warning, read these threads:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099404/ssl-insecureplatform-error-when-using-requests-package and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29134512/insecureplatformwarning-a-true-sslcontext-object-is-not-available-this-prevent

Comment: @GideonAv -- hey! Just wanted to know if there is anything new? Did you check my comment above? did it fix your problem? Thanks.

Comment: @bshuster13 Like I said, I gave up on this package.  (I was able to do what I needed with urllib2.Request)