# Python: save image of CAPTCHA from url

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib, captcha

I need to detect symbols from captcha image, that I get from url.
I use code

```
session = requests.Session()
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml,image/webp,image/apng,image/*,*/*;q=0.8'
    }
html = session.get(page, headers=headers).text
print(session.get(page, headers=headers).url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
img_link = soup.find('img')
urllib.request.urlretrieve(urllib.parse.urljoin(page, img_link['src']), path_name)
```

But I get an error

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)>
```

I check url and img_link['src'], it looks like

```
https://moskva.tiu.ru/Tehnicheskie-moyuschie-sredstva;50
/captcha.gif
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Try using selenium webdriver. You won't have any of these problems

Comment: Use `requests.get(url, verify=False).content` and save to file.

Comment: This is a well known Mac-thing. You can solve it by doing a pip install certifi as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830901/python-requests-throwing-ssl-errors